# do .. while java code wont work correctly

Tags: java, eclipse, do-while

**Hey 
I'm beginning to learn java , 
I wrote this code & when I write admin it keeps looping !

.
.
.**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Don1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String in_user, in_pass;

        do {

            Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println(" Please Login :\n Username :");
            in_user = user.nextLine();

            /*
             * Scanner pass = new Scanner(System.in); System.out.println(
             * " Please Login :\n Password :"); in_pass = pass.nextLine();
             */
        }

        while (in_user != "admin");

        System.out.println("1- Student Operation\n 2- Staff Operations \n 3- Admin Operations");
        System.out.println(in_user);
    }

}
```

**and here is the console process :**

> ```
>  Please Login :
>  Username :
> w
>  Please Login :
>  Username :
> admin
>  Please Login :
>  Username :
> ```

Don't know where is the error :(

Comment: you have to use `equals()` to compare strings

Comment: try this `while(!in_user.equals("admin"))`